# How to create an IF statement in R to trim the final character of cell

Tags: r, if-statement, trim

I have an issue where I concatenate two cells separated by a `", "`. However, if the second cell in the concatenation is blank, the separator still shows.

I'm wondering if I can make an IF statement to output the result whereby

`IF df[2,4] ENDS (", ") THEN {function to trim the comma off} ELSE df[2,4]`

Say I have the following:

```
letters <- c("A", " ", "C")
numbers <- c(1, 2, 3)
names <- c("Matt", "Mark", "Luke")

df <- data.frame(letters, numbers, names)

df$concat <- ""

df[1,4] <- paste(df[1,3], df[1,1], sep = ", ")
df[2,4] <- paste(df[2,3], df[2,1], sep = ", ")
df[3,4] <- paste(df[3,3], df[3,1], sep = ", ")
```

Resulting in:

```
  letters numbers names  concat
1       A       1  Matt Matt, A
2               2  Mark Mark,  
3       C       3  Luke Luke, C
```

So what I want to do is say `IF` any text in the `concat` column ends in `,` then omit JUST the comma

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ifelse` to `paste` the two columns only if `letters` is not empty.

```
df <- transform(df, concat = ifelse(letters != ' ', 
                     paste(names, letters, sep = ','), names))
df

#  letters numbers names concat
#1       A       1  Matt Matt,A
#2               2  Mark   Mark
#3       C       3  Luke Luke,C
```

---

If the dataset is already created you can trim the last comma and whitespace using `trimws`.

```
df$concat <- trimws(df$concat, whitespace = '[\\s,]')
```

Comment: Say I want to simply remove the final character ```IF``` it's a comma from a particular string? Is there a function for this?

Comment: How about using `df$concat <- trimws(df$concat, whitespace = '[\\s,]')` ?

Comment: That worked perfectly!! So that is saying, "Trim whitespace at the end but I am defining my whitespace as a comma"?

Comment: It is a whitespace and a comma. `\\s` is for a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can, as the last step, remove the leftover characters:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(
  letters = c("A", " ", "C"),
  numbers = c(1, 2, 3),
  names = c("Matt", "Mark", "Luke")
) %>%
  mutate(concat = str_c(names, letters, sep = ", ") %>%
           str_remove(",\\s+$"))
#>   letters numbers names  concat
#> 1       A       1  Matt Matt, A
#> 2               2  Mark    Mark
#> 3       C       3  Luke Luke, C
```